# Async file upload with jquery and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have read one article for Async file upload in ASP.NET [here](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2011/12/async-file-upload-with-jquery-and.html).

It is working till the .ashx file call but showing "context.Request.Files.Count" 0.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the HTML form, like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

OR

```
YourForm.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

---

You also need to verify that your HTML `<input>` of type file has a `name` attribute, like this:

```
<input type="file" name="MyFileInput" />
```

Comment: Hi Karl, Thank you for the reply. Everything is there including <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> and <input type="file" name="MyFileInput" /> any other missing things?

Comment: Is this a valid attribute (fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',) to pass file?